# Why do I need multiple mutexes?

Tags: c++, mutex

I am currently looking at a code example below (also can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unique_lock)).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
std::mutex m_a, m_b, m_c;
int a, b, c = 1;
void update()
{
    {   // Note: std::lock_guard or atomic<int> can be used instead
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_a);
        a++;
    }
 
    { // Note: see std::lock and std::scoped_lock for details and alternatives
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk_b(m_b, std::defer_lock);
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk_c(m_c, std::defer_lock);
      std::lock(lk_b, lk_c);
      b = std::exchange(c, b+c);
   }
}
 
int main()
{
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
    threads.emplace_back(update);
 
  for (auto& i: threads)
    i.join();
 
  std::cout << a << "'th and " << a+1 << "'th Fibonacci numbers: "
            << b << " and " << c << '\n';
}
```

Here, I am wondering why this example uses multiple mutexes `m_a, m_b, m_c`.

For instance,

1. Can I only use `m_a, m_b` and do the following?

```
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_a);
        a++;
    }

    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_b);
      b = std::exchange(c, b+c);
   }
```

2. Or, can I only use `m_a` and do the following?

```
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_a);
        a++;
    }

    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_a);
      b = std::exchange(c, b+c);
    }
```

What is the advantage of using multiple mutexes?
I found that all three works identically on my computer.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Short answer is yes. Assumes no where else in the code is referencing `m_b` and `m_c`.

Comment: @selbie, could you share some ideas on advantages of using multiple mutexes?

Comment: This is a contrived example, you wouldn't start 12 threads to compute the 12 fibonachi number. Multiple locks are for locking multiple resources. This is simply an example. Mutliple mutex's don't help you here.

Comment: The idea is that you have one mutex per resource whose access you want to protect independently. If you're fine with making it so that your access is "I have exclusive access to a, b, and c", you can do that with one mutex. If you want to make it so that it's possible to have exclusive access to a without preventing other threads from having access to b and/or c, you need more mutexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have more code, code that modifies only b and code that only reads only c.

Now both of those can run in parallel. If you only have one mutex protecting b and c as a pair then they would block each other.

Overall this looks like an example how to acquire multiple locks and other code that shows why multiple locks would be a good thing are simply missing for simplicity sake.